# "Oops! Something Bad Happened" twice today (now four, times and this one has a cat meme!)

Tags: bug

Twice today when I tried to log out, I received an OOPS! screen. The message ends with:

> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://space.meta.stackexchange.com.

So since I've been invited so nicely, I would "like to give (you) additional information about this error.

- Twice today using laptop w/ Chrome
- Once on 3G "hotspot", once on WiFi
- both on Space Exploration SE
- both logging out, clicked option box to close other sessions
- worked OK when going back to previous screen then clicking log out again.

**note:** it happened again the next day, in fact several times in a row, and from Astronomy SE as well. I was finally able to log out at Electronics SE, not sure if using a different site made the difference or if I just tried enough times.

> [image]

New one!  https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/

> [image]

Comment: SE is beta testing their new "Authentication California" system. ("You can log out any time you like, but you can never leave!")

Comment: @NathanTuggy it looks like they are testing "cat enhancements"